# Remove jQuery validator "remote" rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/ describes how to add and remove a rule from jQuery validator.

As demonstrated at http://jsfiddle.net/h0apn1a1/1/, it doesn't remove the "remote" rule.  How should this be accomplished?

```
var validator = $("#myForm").validate({
     rules: {
         myelement: {
             minlength: 2,
             maxlength: 4,
             required: true,
             remote: {
                 url: "/echo/html/",
                 type: "POST",
                 data: {
                     html: 0,
                     delay: .5
                 }
             }
         }
     },
     messages: {
         myelement: {
             remote: "error message"
         }
     }
 });

 $('#testit').click(function () {
     console.log($('#myelement').rules());
     $('#myelement').rules('remove', 'remote');
     console.log($('#myelement').rules());
     console.log($('#myelement').valid(), validator.element('#myelement'));
 })
```

Comment: actually your code shows that the rule `remote` was removed successfully.

Comment: @RamyNasr  The `console.log` shows it as being removed, but it still initiates an ajax request, and upon the first test, validates as false.

Comment: There is only one way to dynamically remove a rule... `.rules('remove')`.  If you've found a bug with the plugin or if it functions in way that is unexpected, there is not much we can do for you here.  Please make a bug report on the developer's GitHub page.

Comment: @Sparky  Before crying wolf, thought I would ask the question here.  I will do a bit more research, and post a bug report if I don't get anywhere.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: FWIW, there are about 5000 questions tagged jQuery Validate and I've answered over 1100 myself.  The point is not to brag, but to let you know that if your observations are repeatable, it's likely a bug that I've yet to see anyone else complain about here.

Comment: @Sparky  With 1,110 answers, you have rights to brag!  Just doing my due diligence, however...

Comment: It never does the remote call nor fails the validation when I test it. Which browser are you testing this against? I am using chrome on windows.